# Dejar sin espacio a dos li

Tags: css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este Ul li que se queden sin espacio entre los dos Li. ¿Alguna forma de solucionarlo?

Código HTML

`<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Canciones</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>`

Código CSS

`nav{
    line-height: 90px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 30%;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid;
}
nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}`

Comment: Hola, podrías añadir algo de tu código para poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando utilizas `display:inline` o `display_inline-block` siempre se genera una margen entre los elementos

> Este comportamiento de los items con el valor inline-block de dejar un hueco entre cada uno de ellos es consecuencia de la parte que tienen de elemento en línea.

Lo puedes solucionar de la siguiente manera:

```
nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid;
    margin-left: -4px;
}

nav ul li:first-child{
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Te dejo [este link](https://escss.blogspot.com.co/2012/03/display-inline-block-y-sus-empeno-en.html) con una explicación muy clara y otras formas de resolver ese problema.

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: No me funciona con lo que me has puesto , voy a echar un vistazo al link. MUchas gracias

Comment: Y colocaste el `margin-left: -4px;` ? Que raro !

Comment: vale no coloqué el negativo muchas gracias. Una pregunta,¿Porqué es -4px?

Comment: Por que el espacio que se genera es de aproximadamente 4px, entonces al quitarle esos 4px los "unes", es una de las tantas formas de solucionarlo.

Comment: vale muchas gracias por la ayuda :)